# Dictionary serialisation with DataContractserialiser

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dictionary

My method returns `Dictionary<TZerokey, Dictionary<TFirstKey, Dictionary<TSecondKey,Dictionary<TThirdKey,TValue>>>>` and i would to serialise/deserialise this object as XML using DataContractSerialiser.

Below are my methods:

```
public static void SerializeDictionaryToXml<T>(this T obj, string fileName)
{
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    // System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
    ser.WriteObject(fileStream, obj);
    fileStream.Close();
}

public static T DeserializeDictionaryFromXml<T>(string xml)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(xml,
    FileMode.Open);
    XmlDictionaryReader reader =    XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

    // Deserialize the data and read it from the instance.
    T deserializedObject = (T)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
    reader.Close();
    fs.Close();

    return deserializedObject;
}
```

The code runs fine except that I do not get the expected output.  Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and what is the expected output?

Comment: the input is  any Dictionary<TZerokey, Dictionary<TFirstKey, Dictionary<TSecondKey,Dictionary<TThirdKey,TValue>>>> unless this can not be done,

Comment: So, what do you expect if a generic type in one of the dictionaries is not attributed with DataContract?  Or a member is not attributed with DataMember?